# JWPlayer control bar causing post-backs

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

When a user clicks on play/pause, volume, or the full-screen button, the page does a post-back. This has been seen in Chrome 23, IE 9, Safari 5, both for Windows and Mac. Firefox 17 and Opera 12 are okay. The best one probably has to be the full-screen in Safari.

Here's the code I'm using to embed the video:

```
<div id='my-video'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('my-video').setup({
         file: '/videos/Penultimate_Md.mp4',
         image: '/videos/penultimate_first.png',
         width: '480',
         height: '270',
         });
</script>
```

How can this be resolved? Is this just a bug that has nothing to do with me?

### Confirmed

It's a bug in the HTML5 video player. The control bar inputs are all html buttons, which cause the ASP validators to fire (thanks to @Lando for pointing that out). Longtail says it'll be fixed in the next release. Adding `primary: flash,` will work provided the user has flash installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Mike's issue is that the jwplayer has not finished loading. Just add it to the event after the loading of the player. This worked in my code

```
    <div id="my-video">Loading the player...</div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            jwplayer('my-video').setup({
                playlist: [{
                    sources: [{ file: 'SampleVideo.mp4' }]
                }]
            });
            jwplayer().onReady(function (event) {
                $('#my-video button').on('click', function (event) { return false; });
                alert('Ready');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Tried this, but the player never ended up loading...it just sat and said "Loading the video player..."

Comment: Hey Mike.. made a mistake, added the '#' inside the jwplayer('my-video').. I actually came back to fix it and saw your comment. Thanks for your comment to point it out as well!

Comment: Hmm....now the `div` renders and it load the video (you can see it using dev tools) but there's nothing visible - just an empty space. Hovering over it shows there's something there - but nothing happens when you click. Curiouser and curiouser....

Comment: This code above worked perfectly for me. If you're still having trouble check the video? I changed the way the file is loaded in for JW6. This is the suitable way for multiple formats. Flash, MP4, Quicktime..

Comment: Ah. I haven't updated yet. I should probably get around to that.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you if it is really a bug, but the following code in your page is conflicting with your JWPlayer setup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Somehow the html version of the player is triggering the `__doPostBack` which in turn triggers `theForm.submit()` and finally the page reload.

**Workaround 1**

Put the player outside the form.

**Workaround 2**

Switch to **flash** as primary player, you can do that by adding `primary: 'flash'` to your setup, see the code bellow.

```
jwplayer('my-video').setup({
     file: '/videos/Penultimate_Md.mp4',
     image: '/videos/penultimate_first.png',
     width: '480',
     height: '270',
     primary: 'flash'
});
```

Of course this will not solve the issue when flash is not available.

Comment: I'm not *positive*, but I believe that script is auto-generated by asp validators - at any rate, it's present on every page and isn't in the source anywhere. Why would that script conflict with the JWPlayer?

Comment: Somehow the html version of the player is triggering the `__doPostBack` which in turn triggers `theForm.submit()` and the page reload. If you move the player outside of the form it shouldn't reload the page anymore.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a bug, as it only happens with the control bar buttons. If you click on the main screen to play / pause it works normally.

Comment: Oomph. Moving that player outside of the form (defined in the Site.master file) is easier said than done, and not worth re-designing the entire site. `primary: flash' did the trick in everything but IE, and Longtail says it should be fixed in the next update.

Comment: You are right, IE9 is ignoring the flash directive, another bug maybe?

Comment: Actually, that's not true. I realized that I didn't have flash installed for IE, since I never use it except for testing. After installing flash it worked alright in IE.

Answer (score 1):

### The Hack-tastic solution

Seriously. If anyone has a better solution, please tell me.

When JWPlayer detects an HTML 5 compliant browser, it renders the HTML 5 version of the video player. The control-bar buttons are `<button>` elements, which by default cause the ASP.NET validators to fire, which in turn causes a post-back.

Using Javascript/JQuery, I attempted to set the `onclick` attribute of all buttons to `return false;` in the `window.onload` event. However, for some reason, the player hasn't been rendered at that point in the page's life cycle - the JQuery selector `$("button")` returned 0 elements.

So here's what I ended up doing. As noted, this is hack-tacular and I hate it. Hopefully Longtail fixes this soon.

```
<div onclick="disableButtons(); return false;" >                
    <div id='my-video'></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jwplayer('my-video').setup({
            file: '/videos/Penultimate_Md.mp4',
            image: '/videos/penultimate_first.png',
            width: '480',
            height: '270'
            });

function disableButtons() {
    var buttons = $("my-video button");
    buttons.attr('onclick', 'function () { return false; }');

    </script>
</div>
```

So, whenever a user clicks on the `<div>` containing the player, all buttons are set to `return false;`. <strike>**NB** This applys to ALL buttons on the page. If you have any other buttons on your page, it will affect them as well.</strike> I incorporated @goodwince's suggestion, which only targets buttons within the specified `div`.

Comment: Your solution isn't that bad.. you could just change code to be more selective and target the div that is holding the buttons.. $('my-video button').

Comment: Interesting. `$('my-video button')` works, but the JQuery selector still returns 0 elements...not sure what's going on there. But it works, so there's that. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: when testing try a #my-video button